# Bucket Sorting or sorting an arraylist of objects based on Id?

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist

I've heard about the `Bucket Sorting`. Could any one clarify how it gives the best performance when we sort millions of records? Is there any algorithm with `n*log(n)` or `O(n)` 
 ?

I have 1000 employee objects each employee object has id, name, salary properties. I added these objects to `ArrayList` I want to `sort` these objects based on id property. Is there anyway? With out using `Collections.sort()` method. Considered below solutions, please anybody help which one gives best performance?

Thanks

Comment: Yeah. It's called Comparable and Comparator with a dash of Collections.sort :D

Comment: @Thihara My requirement is not to use Collections.sort() method

Comment: This link helps a lot http://www.thejavageek.com/2013/06/17/sorting-user-defined-objects-part-1/

Comment: `My requirement is not to use Collections.sort() method`. Yet you neglected to mention that in your question.

Comment: Dump them into a TreeMap then reinsert them into a ArrayList.  Easy peasy.

Comment: In any practical situation, you should probably use `Collections.sort()`. If it is homework in a basic programming course, then you should probably implement a sorting algorithm yourself (in this case, something simple like a bubble sort is usually enough)

Comment: @MaVRoSCy I edited the question. Please review it and vote for reopen

Comment: @StephenC I edited the question. Please review it and vote for reopen

Comment: @UwePlonus I edited the question. Please review it and vote for reopen

Comment: @assylias  I edited the question. Please review it and vote for reopen .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Without Collections.sort() :**

First implement `Comparable<Employee>` in Empoloyee's class and override `compareTo`

```
@Override
public int compareTo(Employee o) {

    return this.id.compareTo(o.id);
}
```

Pass your unsorted list to `TreeSet` and get `set`(sorted on id) then create `new List` with this `set`

```
List<Employee> list=new ArrayList<Employee>();
    list.add(new Employee(1, "A", Double.parseDouble("50")));
    list.add(new Employee(22, "B", Double.parseDouble("11")));
    list.add(new Employee(3, "C", Double.parseDouble("222")));
    list.add(new Employee(34, "D", Double.parseDouble("4")));

    SortedSet<Employee> set=new TreeSet<Employee>( list);

    List<Employee> l=new ArrayList<Employee>();
    l.addAll(set);

    System.out.println(l);
```

OutPut: Sorted on id without`Collections.sort()`

```
[Employee [id=1, name=A, price=50.0], Employee [id=3, name=C, price=222.0], Employee [id=22, name=B, price=11.0], Employee [id=34, name=D, price=4.0]]
```

**Edit:**

**Employee class:**

```
class Employee implements Comparable<Employee>{

Integer id;
String name;
Double price;
       -------

}
```

Comment: My id property is an integer not a string but compareTo() method supports only string comparision.

Comment: `return this.id.compareTo(o.id);` is the section that uses a `String`. If you employ some common sense, this can EASILY be replaced with integer comparisons.

Comment: Added Employee class also where in is Integer not String . However compareTo methods is overriden in Integer,String and Date classes.Plz check the API

Answer (score 3):

```
public class Employee implements Comparable<Employee> {

private int id;
private String name;
private String salary ;

public int compareTo(Employee val) {
      if(id>val.id){
      return 1;  
    }else if(id<val.id){
        return -1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}

//getter and setters here
}
```

and now you can create a list

```
 List<Employee> emp= new ArrayList<Employee>();
```

Now you can use

```
Collections.sort(emp);
```

to sort by id

Comment: what do you mean by Employee.val?

Comment: yes it was a mistake, Corrected.

Comment: In my case id is not String it is an integer

Comment: @MaheshVarma in that case change compareTo method some thing like my answer

Comment: thanks. Is there any way we can do this with out using compareTo() method?

Comment: @MaheshVarma If you are using this way you should have compareTo() method. it is a implementation of compareTo() method in Comparable interface. We should override that in our code

Answer (score 3):

The `ArrayList` can store element in the ArrayFormat. If you identify user employee by id, you can use `HashTable` class which uses the key and value pair, otherwise you can implement your class using Comparable interface.

```
public class Employee implements Comparable<Employee> {

    private String id;
    private String name;
    private int salary ;

    public int compareTo(Employee val) {
        return id.compareTo(val.id);
    }

    // getter and setters here...

    List<Employee> emp = new ArrayList<Employee>();
    Collections.sort(emp);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
My requirement is not to use Collections.sort() method
```

In that case you need to use some existing way of sorting. If the collection is static (no more items being added) I can recommend using either quicksorting or merge-sorting. If there will be items added, heapsorting or binary sorting is probably the best way to go.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code to sort the list:

```
Collections.sort(list, new Comparator() {
    public int compare(Object a, Object b) {
        Employee ea = (Employee) a;
        Employee eb = (Employee) b;
        return ea.getID() - eb.getID();
    }
}
```

This uses `Collections.sort` to sort the list with a custom comparator, which compares IDs.

If you can't use `Collections.sort`, then surely your teacher told you how to sort a list? Maybe it would pay off to pay attention in the lectures.

Answer (score -1):

First convert it into List of your class:

```
List<Employee> list = new List<Employee>(arraylist);

var sorted = list.OrderBy(o => o.id).ToList();
```

Comment: is => operator works with jdk 6?

Comment: What is more, `List` is an interface. You cannot instantiate it. There is no `var` in Java. Your code looks like C#.